# AMD RX460 on dated hardware

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-rec

I have an older computer, with an i5 3000 series processor (I think 3330 but I'm not sure, I need to check home), about 8 gigs of RAM and a HD7750. I want to upgrade my video card to play Guilty Gear Xrd Revelator at 60 fps constant (for now it runs at about 56-59 with minimum details) and maybe some newer fancier stuff, so I'm conservatively planning to get a RX460. My MOBO has a PCIE-3 slot so I have the connectivity. Am I planning too conservatively? Will this choke on my computer? Am I better off with a 470?

Comment: a 470 is definitely better.  You can then raise your graphics level, maybe even some of the settings on high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your monitor is 1080p,

While your CPU is still perfectly fine, upgrading to an RX 460 means at least a 25% performance boost.

You'd be able to play this game with maxed out graphics but not at 60 fps.

If that really matters, just disable anti-aliasing or even upgrade to an RX 470 for more bang for your bucks.

Comment: thanks for the realistic numbers. I'll think about it. Sadly RX470 cost at least 120 euros if not more than a RX460 here.